# why am I getting column main_category.parent_cat_id does not exist

Tags: python, django, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

So every thing works fine in development but as soon as I do eb deploy this problem occurs again. I don't have related_cat in my code.

```
  ProgrammingError at /admin/main/category/
column main_category.parent_cat_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...n_category"."author_id", "main_category"."image", "main_cate...
                                                             ^

class Category(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name=('community'))
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=('image'))
    # parent_cat = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)
    hotCat = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    sponsored = models.ForeignKey(Sponsored, null=True, blank=True)


    objects = CategoryManager()

    def __unicode__(self): 
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/category/%s/" %self.name

    def get_image_url(self):
        return "%s%s" %(settings.MEDIA_URL, self.image)
```

Comment: This error means that you have inconsistencies in model definition and sql schema of your db. Did you make all migrations especially for commented `parent_cat` field?

Comment: @crash843 yes I did python manage.py migrate, more importantly I'm using elastic beanstalk which does migrate when getting uploaded

Comment: Just to clarify, Elastic Beanstalk doesn't automatically do migrate, you need something like this in your .ebextensions/config.

    `03_migrateapp:
        command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py migrate --noinput"
        leader_only: true`